# Encoding an ampersand for twitter w/ curl

Tags: curl, twitter, character-encoding

Here's my code:

```
curl -u "u:d" --data-urlencode "status=`echo $@|tr ' ' '+'|tr '&' '%26'`" "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json"
```

But when it goes to twitter, the '&' turns into '%'. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tr` performs individual character replacement.

It replaces `&` with `%` because that's what you told it to do.

You want something like `sed` which does more than just character-by-character substitution.

Answer (score 0):

sed "s/\&/\%26/g"