# How to include an '&' character in a bash curl statement

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to use curl in bash to download a webpage, but the `&` symbol in the URL isn't interpreted as a character as I would like. Any ideas on how I can convince bash that the symbol `&` is just a boring character and nothing special?

Comment: Have a look at the following topic this should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067969/encoding-an-ampersand-for-twitter-w-curl

Comment: I've tried replacing the `&` symbol with `\&`, `'&'`, `"&"`, `^&` but haven't been able to get the URL to evaluate correctly. Actually, the `'&'` works when I run the curl command from Terminal.app, but fails when I place it in a bash script, wrap it in a loop and run it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Putting single quotes around the `&` symbol seems to work. That is, using a URL like `http://www.example.com/page.asp?arg1=${i}'&'arg2=${j}` with curl returns the requested webpage.

Comment: you should include the argument requirement on the question so that it is clear for future views.

Comment: Why this answer is accped? This answer must be acceped http://stackoverflow.com/a/13339492/2898694

Answer (score 178):

Putting the entire URL inside double quotes should take care of your problem.

Comment: single quotes might be better, unless there's a need to resolve variables.

Comment: When I use quotes around the whole URL the expression `${i}` doesn't return a value.

Comment: In my case, double quotes failed while single quotes worked just fine.

Comment: Please use caution what program is used to type the quotes.  While in a hurry to edit a shell script, I used a text editing program. It put slanted quotes instead of straight double quotes. This really messes up the script and makes the problem difficult to find!

Comment: Single quotes do not work in my .cmd file, but double quotes work

Comment: Confirmed windows needs double quotes and also make sure there are no spaces, leading or trailing, inside the quotes.

Answer (score 60):

```
curl "http://www.example.com?m=method&args=1"
```

Are you using the & as a delimiter for a GET URL? Or is in a piece of data?

If it is in data you must encode it to an HTML character, if not, surround with quotes.

The encoding for `&` should become `%26` in the URL.

```
curl "http://www.example.com?m=this%26that
```

Comment: I'm using the `&` symbol as a piece of data, almost exactly as you've shown. The catch is that, instead of numerical values I'm using `${i}`. So I want to get `http://www.example.com?m=method&args=${i}` to evaluate as a URL.

Comment: The way I just showed the URL uses the '&' as a delimeter for the GET variables, so now I am confused, in $[i] you have a piece of data that contains '&'? If that is the case you will need to URL encode it.

& = %26

Comment: Searched the whole internet couldn't find the solution. @MattClark you are the hero. I just url encoded & which was a piece of data and my script is working fine.

Comment: Is there a missing " at the end of the second code snippet?

Answer (score 25):

Instead of trying the escape "&" characters, you can specify http url parameters in POST requests with -d parameter as shown below:

```
curl -X POST http://www.example.com \
-d arg1=this \
-d arg2=that
```

If the request is a GET, then you should also add -G option, which tells curl to send the data with GET request.

```
curl -X GET -G http://www.example.com \
-d arg1=this \
-d arg2=that
```

Comment: This worked for me. Adding double quotes didn't work.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `%26` instead `&`.
The entity code will work fine.

Answer (score 6):

Use the parameter `--url` with double quotes worked for me

Answer (score 3):

easiest way :

```
curl -X GET -G http://example.com -d var1=$1 -d var2=$2
```