# CherryPy only receiving 1st query string parameter

Tags: python, get, cherrypy

I've just begun my journey into the realms of the CherryPy module in Python. It's pretty awesome how easy it makes it to setup a server with a RESTful api, however I've ran into an issue. My code is only acknowledging the first parameter in a query string.

I want to make a GET request like so:
`curl -X GET 127.0.0.1:8080/api/sum/?a=2&b=3`

My Python code is as follows:

```
import cherrypy

class getSum:
    exposed = True
    def GET(self, **params):
        a = float(params['a'])
        b = float(params['b'])
        return a+b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.tree.mount(getSum(), '/api/sum/', {'/': {'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()}})
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

After fiddling with the code for a while I've come to the following diagnosis:
When the query string is being read into `params`, instead of starting a new entry in the dictionary when it reaches the '&' it just stops instead.

Has anyone got any advice on how to read multiple parameters in as a single query string?

With Thanks, Sean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python script posted in my question is actually a working implementation of what I wanted to do. The problem was instead with the curl request that I was making.

The '&' character in my curl request was truncating my bash command, resulting in this: `curl -X GET 127.0.0.1:8080/api/sum/?a=2`

The fix for this is to wrap my url in quotes like so: `curl -X GET "127.0.0.1:8080/api/sum/?a=2&b=3"`

When executing this command `5.0` is returned to the terminal, as expected.

This following post contains a useful discussion on the use of ampersands in curl requests: [How to include an '&' character in a bash curl statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339469/how-to-include-an-character-in-a-bash-curl-statement)