# GET Request with parameters in CURL

Tags: curl, shopify

I send a request to the Shopify api in javascript to the following url:

```
https://someauthorizationkey.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/orders.json?id=12334445'
```

and it works perfectly. I get exactly the request order, everything works find.

If I do the same in curl with the following command:

```
curl -k https://someauthorizationkey.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/orders.json?id=12334445
```

I get **all** orders, as if I haven't use the parameter id=12334445.

How do I correct the command in curl to get only the order with the specific id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by using the verbose mode and reading this post: [How to include an '&' character in a bash curl statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339469/how-to-include-an-character-in-a-bash-curl-statement)

The url needs to be in quotes "", because of the ampersand being converted, if not in quotes.