# Get the pages source using php and python

Tags: php, python

I'm running into an issue while web scraping. I'm using PHP for scraping, but there's this certain website where I have to use Python instead. My solution was to call a Python script from PHP to get the page source, as my main script must be written in PHP.

The Python code below works great when I call it using *Python*:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
link = 'websitelink'
driver.get(link)
s = driver.page_source
print((s.encode("utf-8")))
driver.quit()
```

The Python code below is what I use within the PHP script, because I'm passing the website URL to it as a variable:

```
import sys
link = sys.argv[1]
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
driver.get(link)
s = driver.page_source
print((s.encode("utf-8")))
driver.quit()
```

This is the PHP code where i call the Python script:

```
$page_html =  shell_exec('python3.6 test.py '.$url);
```

So the intended result is that `page_html` will have the page content from the website.

The problem is that my website URL has page 1, page2, page 3... and in PHP I only receive the first page, yet when I use just the Python script I can get the correct results. I lost 2 days of my life on this; does someone have an idea why I don't receive the entire page contents when I start the Python script from PHP?

Comment: This probably needs some sort of additional escaping of the $url parameter for the shell context.

Comment: @misorude can you explain a little bit what did you mean?

Comment: Could perhaps be as simple as putting the URL in quotes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339469/how-to-include-an-character-in-a-bash-curl-statement

Comment: OMG, yes that was a problem!