# Multiple parameters to falcon service

Tags: falconframework

I have a `falcon` script that I am trying to pass multiple `parameters` to:

```
import falcon
import random
import os
import time


waitTime = int(os.environ.get('WAIT_TIME', '2'))

class SomeFunc(object):
    def on_get(self, req, response):
        req.path, _, query = req.relative_uri.partition('?')
        query = falcon.uri.decode(query)
        decoded_params = falcon.uri.parse_query_string(query, keep_blank=True, csv=False)
        print(decoded_params)

    ...


api = falcon.API()
api.add_route('/func', SomeFunc())
```

I need to pass n `parameters` to this service. However, when I call it:

```
curl localhost:8000/servicedb?limit=12&time=1
```

It prints out **just** the first parameter:

```
{'limit': '12'}
```

What is the correct code on the `client/server` to get all parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it looks like your Falcon code does what you expect it to, just (depending on the shell you use) you most likely forgot to escape the `curl` invocation, which essentially forks a shell command `time=1`.

See also: [How to include an '&' character in a bash curl statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339469/how-to-include-an-character-in-a-bash-curl-statement).

Sending the request as

```
curl "http://localhost:8000/func?limit=12&time=1"
```

I get the below output:

```
{'limit': '12', 'time': '1'}
```

In addition, while not directly causing any problems, you don't really need to manually parse the URI that way.
Simple reference [`req.params`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response_wsgi.html#falcon.Request.params) to get obtain all parameters at once, or use the specialized [`req.get_param_*()`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response_wsgi.html#falcon.Request.get_param) methods to get the value of a single parameter.

For example:

```python
import falcon


class SomeFunc(object):
    def on_get(self, req, response):
        print(req.params)
        print(req.get_param_as_int('limit'))


app = falcon.App()
app.add_route('/func', SomeFunc())
```

now prints:

```
{'limit': '12', 'time': '1'}
12
```