# Enterprise License Manager API Backend Error

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am try to call Google Enterprise License Manager API, but server always response "Backend Error". I don't know that this problem is my code error or Google's server error. Can anyone help me find out a solution.

My call:

```
curl 'https://licensing.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/Google-Apps/users?customerId=????????&maxResults=50' \
   --header 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.c.b0AXv0zTPL5sgZnTg2_pdWuz37RlXj_CLry9EiAAwXpr8ss-Gdi1fiR3ZP7KquPzcF93-lSgDJ3cyC8hn3rU5ixZNvg8ZFg8X9am8AMsF2QnpAfMcKkJDlW_fG61mwkoA_Cfc4k5SRJgkIB6mGPy5HVUcXy_SxMre15zAuVVWNsQXROIqxmpFBEtMz1c4ZzbTJuuIqZqnxkz3lc04xEmqoP9KH78YkGEo' \
   --header 'Accept: application/json' \
   --compressed
```

The response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "Backend Error",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Backend Error",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "backendError"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess but you may need to use double quotes instead of single quotes.  See e.g. [How to include an '&' character in a bash curl statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13339469) and [Curl single quotes vs. double quotes](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/curl-single-quotes-vs-double-quotes/114671).

Comment: Also, please [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) your question to indicate the command line / environment from which you are calling curl, e.g. [tag:bash] or [tag:powershell] or whatever.