# Non UTF character breaking cURL response

Tags: json, curl

The return I am looking for, looks like this in the API sandbox (Browser driven):

```
{
"reviewId": "2887600825207199304",
"rating": 5,
"comments": "Abe Froeman  provided a â€œseamlessâ€ gutter experience.  Abe managed the scheduling, and Ferris and Cameron, with 15-30+ years of experienced, executed the job beautifully.  Extremely diligent workers.  Looks very attractive.  Would highly recommend for future jobs.",
"title": null,
...
..
.
```

But in the back end, when I issue the curl statement:

```
zak $ curl -d  "$(cat input.json)" \
> -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
> -H "Accept: application/json" \
> -X POST "https://api/xx.com/v1/xxx?sindex=0&count=30&api_key=..."
```

My return looks like

```
{
"reviewId": "2887600825207199304",
"rating": 5,
"comments": "Abe Froeman  provided a â€œseamlessâ€zak $  <-- Broken
```

All my research ends up in questions about encoding the URL .. Not dealing with the response -- IE [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339469/how-to-include-an-character-in-a-bash-curl-statement)

**Problem:** Non UTF ( I think! ) character from API breaking cURL response

**Attempts:** Have been fruitless, I've tried many different flags from `man curl` -- none seem to help

**Question:** How do I get cURL to ignore the erroneous characters returned from an API?

Comment: Doesn't it just break on the console? What happens if you let curl store it to a file?

Comment: Now that DOES work .. Why would the CLI fail here?

Comment: Because the cli only handles utf-8. You can't print binary data on the console (which is what non-utf8 bytes are)

Comment: Either point me to an SO question that's a duplicate, so we can close this properly, or answer it with your explanation and I'll accept.